# I can't fetch temp table data from store procudere

Tags: php, sql-server

I created on store procedure in sql server below is the structure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[list_final_player_report]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @teamid int
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
                        playername varchar(50),
                        RANK_in_speedladdar INT,
                        rank_in_120s int,
                        rank_in_cone int,
                        rank_in_beep int,
                        rank_in_cooper int,
                        rank_in_pushups int,
                        rank_in_situp int,
                        rank_in_pullup int,
                        rank_in_40s int,
                        rank_in_pushopbattle int,
                        rank_in_vertical_jump int,
                        rank_in_shuttle int
                    )
DECLARE @playerid int
DECLARE @firstname nvarchar(10) 

-- Define the cursor
DECLARE cursor1 cursor for
select Players.PlayerID as PlayerID , players.firstname  from Players where Teamid=@teamid

-- We should open the cursor
OPEN cursor1

-- We need to Fetch the rows into @EmpId variable
FETCH cursor1 into @playerid,@firstname

--Looping
WHILE(@@fetch_status=0)
BEGIN

insert into #TempTable 
values(@firstname,
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =1 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid ),
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =2 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid ),
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =3 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid ) ,
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =4 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid ) ,
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =5 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid ) ,
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =6 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid ) ,
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =7 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid ) ,
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =8 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid ) ,
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =9 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid ) ,
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =10 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid ) ,
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =11 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid ) ,
(select  (sum(Total))/count(PlayerID)  from ChallengeStats WHERE ChallengeStats.ChallengeID =12 and ChallengeStats.PlayerID=@playerid )  
)

FETCH cursor1 into @playerid,@firstname
END

close cursor1
deallocate cursor1 
select * from #TempTable
END
```

this sp is perfectly execute in sqlserver

but the problem is now how to get this temp table data into php resultset

Comment: can you show you php code?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a temp table, why not use a Table variable.
You should not have to change much code in order to get this implemented.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (
                        playername varchar(50),
                        RANK_in_speedladdar INT,
                        rank_in_120s int,
                        rank_in_cone int,
                        rank_in_beep int,
                        rank_in_cooper int,
                        rank_in_pushups int,
                        rank_in_situp int,
                        rank_in_pullup int,
                        rank_in_40s int,
                        rank_in_pushopbattle int,
                        rank_in_vertical_jump int,
                        rank_in_shuttle int
                    )
```

Temp tables are only good during the scope of where they are used, which is what could be causing your issue. Try the above, and you should get a different result.

Comment: but it is perfectly working in sql server..probl is fetching/displaying that temp table.

Comment: fair enough, but it is seems as if you are losing the scope before it can return the data to the calling page. Using the Table Vairable should sort this out for you...